# How can I log in as another user in Firebase PHP with a freshly minted token?

Tags: javascript, php, firebase-authentication

I have a Javascript website using Firebase authentication, and I would like to be able to log into this front-end as if I were another user. Using the PHP Kreait library I can mint a token for a particular uid using:

`$firebase->getAuth()->createCustomToken($firebaseId)`

I can then post this custom token to the REST endpoint like this:

`https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithCustomToken?key=MYKEY`
`POST fields: token={$customToken}&returnSecureToken=true`

..and I get a valid Firebase Auth Token. So far, so good BUT now when I try to use this token to login in Javascript like this:

`firebase.auth().signInWithCustomToken(firebaseToken)`

.. I get "**auth/invalid-custom-token The custom token format is incorrect format site**".

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: There are a lot of things that could be going wrong in your code between the time you get the token from the REST API and passing along to the JS API.  Could you share more code, along with debugging details (such as logging), that illustrate how data is making it from one place to another?

Comment: So, just going off of the title "log in as another user", immediately throws up red flags from a security standpoint.